# Distribution of a time span across months

Tags: excel, date

I a process have a Start date of 1/1/2022 and end date of 3/15/2022, date  is in it's own field.

Now I have a field for every Month in the Year: J F M A M etc.

I want to calculate that my process covers 100% of January and February and 50% of March. In order to calculate this, I added the start and end date for each month below the field like this :

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqgwK.png)

Any help how I can calculate this would be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Made some dits that hopefully clarifies the issue.